# Change or add attributes to model on create/edit with JSONAPI Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-resources

I'm trying to figure out how to use this [jsonapi-resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) gem but I'm finding it quite difficult.

Let's say I just submitted an object like:

```
{"name":"My product","price":"15.00"}
```

But what I want to be saved in the database is something like:

```
{"name":"My Product","price":"15.00","slug":"my-product","series":301234351}
```

In other words, I want to intercept the creation or the update and add or alter the data being sent.

In my particular case I got a "Category" model as following:

**Controller**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
end
```

**Model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

**Resource**

```
class CategoryResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attribute :name #,:slug
  has_many :posts
end
```

**Route**

```
jsonapi_resources :categories
```

How can I add, for example, slug, short-name, last_update to the Category model (assuming it was not passed by the client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class CategoryResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attribute :name #,:slug
  has_many :posts

  before_save do
    # add logic to change or add attributes to model on create/edit 
    # for example
    @model.slug = # logic to assign the slug
    @model.series = # logic to assign the series
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you have slug column in database.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  before_save do
    self.slug = name.gsub(' ', '-').downcase
  end
end
```